# react-native Pod install is not working due to EXImageLoader

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

So I need to add firebase cloud functions in developing react-native project. So before it was working fine, but now it gives me error. What I did so far,

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app yarn add @react-native-firebase/functions
```

then I tried to `cd ios/ && pod install` but it gives me this error below

```
etching podspec for glog from ../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "EXImageLoader": In Podfile: EXImageLoader (from ../node_modules/expo-image-manipulator/node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios)

Specs satisfying the EXImageLoader (from ../node_modules/expo-image-manipulator/node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v13.1.0 but found v14.0.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/storage' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v12.9.3 but found v14.0.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v13.1.0 but found v14.0.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/storage' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v12.9.3 but found v14.0.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
```

Desired: I need to solve this so I can run the project. Right now the pod install is not working I need to resolve this issue to run the project.

of course after this failure, the app is stuck I am using expo start to run the project. Please help I could not find any information on online.

Answer (score 4):

```
expo install expo-image-loader
```

Comment: this package is already installed in the project.